# PHP: Read TXT file and make each line a variable (split line with ,) (This is for a user ranking system)

Tags: php

So i wondered how could I create a php script that read a line and make the line a variabel? for example:

( Also like in css, make the variable equals to everything inside ':' and ';' )

So if the line does not include ':' and ';' it will only put the variable to true.

Administrator.txt

```
/*
   Administrator config
*/
has_admin_chat,
has_mod_chat,
has_loggedin_public_chat,
has_power: 60;,
has_ban_client_with_power_lower_than: 20;,
has_basic_user_tools,
has_report_access,
has_kick_client

And also when , is not included on a line it will not read more of the file
```

So when this file has been read it will be possible to do for example this:

permission_check.php

```
if($has_admin_chat === true){ /* Then do something */ }
```

Now also i will have another file wich will be: `listofpermissions.txt`
So it would have to read `listofpermissions.txt` before actually check the users permissions.

Okay, so to be a little bit more clearly, what I am trying to say is that I want something like:

php read all permissions, and then check the users rank in database (NOT A QUESTION, I KNOW THIS xD), read rank file, whenever trying to access something that needs power to it

```
Now in this part it will make each line a variable,
after that it is gonna check if every permissions are there,
and if not, it will basicly put the variable from listofallperms.txt
    $has_logout=false;
```

, it is kinda similar to the minecraft permission node thing.

**NOTE:** I am really sorry if this was hard to understand, it is a little hard to explain what I am wondering of, I have litterly been looking for days for functions like this.

Example:

Administrator.txt

```
/*
   Administrator config
*/
has_admin_chat,
has_mod_chat,
has_loggedin_public_chat,
has_power: 60;,
has_ban_client_with_power_lower_than: 20;,
has_basic_user_tools,
has_report_access
has_kick_client
```

But now it does not have the permission of `has_logout`
so it will just put the variable eaquals to `false`

**EDIT:** Will it be possible for me to store all of this information in a database, and create a table for each rank?

Also, this is a template I am creating.. So another people can download this and create their own permissions and groups

**Edit 2:** Thanks, this did work. I am not really good with arrays, and have never really got anything to work with it.. But now as i got a nice example i got it to work! Thanks a lot!

> @Sumurai8 I didn't like either, just doing what OP ask for. The proper solution will be an array with keys, like `$permissions['had_admin_chat'] => true`

**Answer by:** Felippe Duarte

Comment: You can use `file` to read the entire file into an array.

Comment: But i just wonder how, and i am not quietly good with arrays :(

Comment: xD sorry,  I'm not english, Thank you, i will edit

Comment: Use a file format that is more standard: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: You can also store your configuration in JSON, or even directly in a PHP array, no processing necessary.

Comment: EDIT: Will it be possible for me to store all of this information in a database, and create a table for each rank?

Also, this is a template I am creating.. So another people can download this and create their own permissions and groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--EDITED to make it better --

I think that is what you want:

```
$handle = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $parts = explode(":", $line);
        if (count($parts) == 1) {
           $parts[1] = true;
        } else {
           $parts[1] = strstr(',',$parts[1],true);

        $$parts[0] = $parts[1]; //here we create your $had_admin = true;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Comment: Will this mean that i have to write:

    >$has_admin_chat = strstr(trim($line),',', true);
    >$$has_admin_chat = true;
Over and over again for each permission node?

Comment: No, just use if($had_admin_chat) { ... logic her }

Comment: I've made a edit with part of Reto, after better understending of your problem. Check again.

Comment: for what i undersand on `$myVar = strstr(trim($line),',', true);` it will basicly not ready the line if it does not include the `,`. Am I Right?

Comment: I strongly recommend against creating random variables, despite that this is in OP's question. Use a permission array if you must, but don't randomly create variables and have it override something accidentally.

Comment: I didn't know that you will have empty lines. You need to have a pattern in your file to make your search easier.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I didn't like either, just doing what OP ask for. The proper solution will be an array with keys, like $permissions['had_admin_chat'] => true

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fgets()` function to read the file line by line. Afterwards you can use the `explode()` function on each line to obtain the key and the value part and do whatever you want to do with em.

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $parts = explode(":", $line);
        if (count($parts) == 2) {
           doSomething($parts[0], $parts[1]);
        }
        else {
           echo 'key '.$part[0].' has no value';
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
function doSomething($key, $value) {
   // process key/value
}
```